# where to use gethostname in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, session-variables

**Objective:** I want to know if it is possible to determine whether the host is localhost or my development site's host in *one place* in the Zend Framework and use that determination across the rest of the site via a session variable.

**Details:** I'm working on a website with a small group of people. We're using svn tools to merge our code, and testing on localhost before moving changes and additions up to a development server. Since the same code is used in every platform we use `gethostname()` in php to determine if we're accessing our site through localhost or the server. We need this so we can set file paths appropriately (`http://localhost/images/dog.jpg` vs `https://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg`). Initially, every time this came into play we set a variable $host in the controller's `public function init()` that contained the appropriate string to use throughout that page. Then we switched to putting $host in a session variable which significantly decreased the amount of redundant code. But I'm sure there is a way to set this in *one place* and be done with it, but I don't know where this place would be (within the Zend framework). The index landing page doesno't work because users will likely enter from other places. My best guess was setting it in the layout, but that gives me errors because the layout code runs too late the page loading process. Is there a better place to determine the host? Is there a way to prioritize it within the layout code so it somehow executes before it's needed in the page?

**Code:**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['hostname'])){
  $hostname = gethostname();
  if ($hostname == 'prodserver') { 
    $_SESSION['hostname'] = 'https://mysite.com'; 
  } else { 
    $_SESSION['hostname'] = 'http://localhost'; 
  }
}
```

Our current method works just fine, but I can't shake the feeling that there must be a better way! If you know it - I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding the hostname to generated URL's in the first place?

Comment: So we can do full path calls. (That part was not my decision.)

Comment: Just use absolute paths, i.e. a path that starts with a `/`. There's no reason to include the hostname on internal links, it just adds complexity.

Comment: I agree with Tim, there is no reason to use the full scheme, host, and port on internal URL's. just use `/` or `//` (for current scheme) and let the system take care of the rest. IMO. whoever made that decision made an incredibly poor one. If you need to ensure something is https coming out of an http page set up HTTPS redirects for pages that must be HTTPS.

Comment: Fair enough, all. Thanks. I'll see what I can do about switching to absolute paths, however, even if that gets resolved we still have some information that get's printed depending on whether we're testing in localhost or not so the answer would still be useful. MORE IMPORTANTLY: I'm really just curious about this. :-) Can a session variable be set in one place and apply to the whole site, no matter what page a user accesses it from? The specific application isn't as important to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in your comment, no, session variables are by definition user-specific. However ZF (by convention) sets the constant `APPLICATION_ENV` which can be used to do environment-specific checks. You can also set variables (including the baseUrl) via. application.ini which would be how would you solve the problem in your question if you needed to.

Comment: Ahh! application.ini makes sense. Thank you.